# Cosine rule problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Question:
In triangle ABC, BC = a, AC= b, AB = c, and BD is perpendicular to AC.
If $\angle ABC = 60^{\circ}$, prove that $c = \dfrac{1}{2}a \pm \sqrt{b^2-\dfrac{3}{4}a^2}$

My approach: $b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos B$

$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2ac \cos{60}^\circ$

$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - ac$

$b^2 = (a-c)^2+ac$

After this I don't know how to isolate the $c$ term.

Comment: $c^2-ac+a^2-b^2=0$ is a 2nd grade equation for $c$: solve it with the standard formula.

Comment: I got the answer. Should I post it as an answer to this question?

Comment: @aretino it doesnt yield the result

Comment: You can rather edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work is correct. Picking up your work from $b^2=a^2+c^2-ac$, subtract $b^2$ from both sides and rewrite to get
$$c^2-ac+a^2-b^2=0$$
which is quadratic in $c$. Notice this equation fits the standard quadratic form with $A=1$, $B=-a$ and $C=a^2-b^2$.

Using the quadratic formula, we get
$$c=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4(a^2-b^2)}}{2}$$
$$c=\frac{a}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{4b^2-3a^2}}{2}$$
$$c=\frac{a}{2}\pm\sqrt{b^2-\frac{3}{4}a^2}\quad.$$

Comment: Nice answer. I posted my version of the answer too in case anybody sees this question and would like to see another way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with the standard formula for a quadratic equation then you can approach it like this:
$$\begin{align}
b^2 &= a^2 + c^2 - ac\\
\therefore c^2-ac&=b^2-a^2\\
\therefore \left(c-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\frac{a^2}{4}&=b^2-a^2\\
\therefore \left(c-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2&=\frac{a^2}{4}+b^2-a^2=b^2-\frac{3a^2}{4}\\
\therefore c-\frac{a}{2}&=\pm\sqrt{b^2-\frac{3a^2}{4}}\\
\therefore c&=\frac{a}{2}\pm\sqrt{b^2-\frac{3a^2}{4}}
\end{align}$$
This technique is called completing the square.

Comment: Ya I figured this out, and posted it a few minutes ago as an answer. I actually do know the quadratic formula, but I was too stupid to see that I could use it...

Comment: No problems - and it does not mean that you are stupid - just human like the rest of us :)

Comment: Thanks haha, still, kinda disappointed that I didn't see it from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

From $b^2 = a^2 + c^2 -ac$

$b^2 - a^2 = c^2 - ac$

$b^2 - \dfrac{3}{4}a^2 = c^2- ac + \dfrac{1}{4}a^2$

$b^2 - \dfrac{3}{4}a^2 = (c-\dfrac{1}{2}a)^2$

$c-\dfrac{1}{2}a = \pm \sqrt{b^2 - \dfrac{3}{4}a^2}$

$c = \dfrac{1}{2}a \pm \sqrt{b^2 - \dfrac{3}{4}a^2}$